# jquery datatables recordsFiltered recordsTotal

Tags: jquery, datatables, dynamically-generated

I have a table that uses a DTResult for passing the data. How do I dynamically change `recordsFiltered` and `recordsTotal` instead of hard coding them? Right now my code looks like this:

```
DTResult<NAME> result = new DTResult<NAME>
{
    draw = staff.Draw,
    data = source,
    recordsFiltered = 100,
    recordsTotal = 100
};
```

Comment: Excuse my ignorance, but what is  a `DTResult`?

Comment: in my understanding it recognizes everything as a result from your code. that way you can return the method as a json result. it is recognized by jquery datatables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `DTResult` looks a custom class which returns json in the format required. You can just as easily use `return Json(new{...`

Anyway, if `data = source` is the property that contains the table data, then you can simply populate the recordsFiltered count from `source`:

```
DTResult<NAME> result = new DTResult<NAME>
{
    draw = staff.Draw,
    data = source,
    recordsFiltered = source.Count(),
    recordsTotal = source.Count()
};
```

Datatables returned data [documentation](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side#Returned-data)

Comment: Do you by chance know how to use recordsTotal on the other side of this?  Like, in the jQuery DataTable constructor?